running sum of np.array with widely varying elements
I need to calculate the running sum of np.array. Let's say a is a given np.array of length l and n is an integer step, then I need an array b of length l - n + 1, where
b= [a[0]+a[1]+...+a[n-1], a[1]+a[2]+...+a[n], ..., a[l-n]+a[l-n+1]+...+a[l-1]]
I tried the following:
def run_sum(a, n):     
    a_cumsum = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(a)]     
    b = a_cumsum[n:] - a_cumsum[:-n]     
    return b

It works fine BUT if array a has very different elements (for example some of them are 1e8 and some of them are 1e-8) like in my case then this method gives too much error, which is accumulated in np.cumsum. Do you have any ideas on how to do this directly, without using np.cumsum?
Since a has lengh int(1e8) I don't want to use for cycle. Woud like to have something like:
ind = np.arange(a.size - n + 1)
b[ind] = np.sum(a[ind:ind+n])

but it doesn't work(
Update, example of a loss of precision:
a = np.array([-9999.999966666666, -5.7847991744735696e-08, -2.983181169098924e-08, -2.093995193995538e-08, -1.6894298480290635e-08, -1.4869270858640853e-08, -1.3961300790320832e-08, -1.3834651535607362e-08, -1.4395718046705324e-08, -1.570696320519037e-08])

run_sum(a, 3) = 
np.array([-9999.999966754345, -1.0861913324333727e-07, -6.766640581190586e-08, -5.2703398978337646e-08, -4.5723936636932194e-08, -4.2664396460168064e-08, -4.219145921524614e-08, -4.393768904265016e-08])

a[:-2] + a[1:1] + a[2:] = 
np.array([-9999.999966754345, -1.0861975537568031e-07, -6.766606211123524e-08, -5.2703521278886865e-08, -4.572487012925232e-08, -4.266522318456905e-08, -4.2191670372633516e-08, -4.393733278750305e-08])

The difference in the 5th figure is important for me!
Update 2:
Think this will work. At least this toy example is processed well. The idea is to split initial array into arrays with large and small elements and to count cumsum independently.
def run_sum_new(a, n, max_exp_sep=3, exp_sep_lim=4):
    """
    Finds the running sum of n consecutive elements of array a. If exponents of array elements
    vary greatly, divides them into different arrays to minimize the final error.

    Receives:
    a - the original array
    n - number of elements to sum
    max_exp_sep - the maximum number of arrays the original array can be divided into (regardless for positive and negative elements).
                  In total, the maximum number of arrays is 2*max_exp_sep+1
    exp_sep_lim - the minimum of the difference between the exponents of two elements at which they must be separated.

    Returns:
    run_sum - array of running sum of the original array
    """

    #finds maximal exponents of pos and neg elements and minimal exponent of elements of a
    a_pos = a[a>0]
    a_neg = a[a<0]
    if a_pos.size == 0:
        a_pos_max = np.nan
    else:
        a_pos_max = np.max(a_pos)
    if a_neg.size == 0:
        a_neg_max = np.nan
    else:
        a_neg_max = np.max(np.abs(a_neg))
    a_min = np.min(np.abs(a))
    exp_pos_max = np.ceil(np.log10(a_pos_max))
    exp_neg_max = np.ceil(np.log10(a_neg_max))
    exp_min = np.floor(np.log10(a_min))
    del(a_pos)
    del(a_neg)

    #finds separation limits list
    d_exp_pos = exp_pos_max - exp_min
    if np.isnan(d_exp_pos):
        exp_pos_sep_list = []
    elif d_exp_pos <= exp_sep_lim * (max_exp_sep + 1):
        exp_pos_sep_list = [10**(exp_min + exp_sep_lim * i) for i in range(1, max_exp_sep+1) if 10**(exp_min + exp_sep_lim * i) < a_pos_max]
    else:
        new_exp_sep_lim = np.ceil(d_exp_pos / (max_exp_sep + 1))
        print(f"Warning: positive elements of array have too large exponent spread {d_exp_pos} for the given max_exp_sep={max_exp_sep} and exp_sep_lim={exp_sep_lim}.",
              f"New exp_sep_lim={new_exp_sep_lim} has been taken.", sep='\n')
        exp_pos_sep_list = [10**(exp_min + new_exp_sep_lim * i) for i in range(1, max_exp_sep+1)]
    d_exp_neg = exp_neg_max - exp_min
    if np.isnan(d_exp_neg):
        exp_neg_sep_list = []
    elif d_exp_neg <= exp_sep_lim * (max_exp_sep + 1):
        exp_neg_sep_list = [-10**(exp_min + exp_sep_lim * i) for i in range(1, max_exp_sep+1) if 10**(exp_min + exp_sep_lim * i) < a_neg_max]
    else:
        new_exp_sep_lim = np.ceil(d_exp_neg / (max_exp_sep + 1))
        print(f"Warning: negative elements of array have too large exponent spread {d_exp_neg} for the given max_exp_sep={max_exp_sep} and exp_sep_lim={exp_sep_lim}.",
              f"New exp_sep_lim={new_exp_sep_lim} has been taken.", sep='\n')
        exp_neg_sep_list = [10**(exp_min + new_exp_sep_lim * i) for i in range(1, max_exp_sep+1)]
    exp_neg_sep_list.reverse()
    exp_sep_list = [-np.inf, ] + exp_neg_sep_list + exp_pos_sep_list + [np.inf,]

    #separates a
    a_sep_list = [np.where((i <= a) & (a < j), a, 0) for (i, j) in zip(exp_sep_list[:-1], exp_sep_list[1:])]
    a_sep_arr = np.array(a_sep_list)

    #finds run sum
    a_sep_cumsum = np.cumsum(a_sep_arr, axis=-1)
    a_sep_cumsum = np.hstack(([[0]]*a_sep_cumsum.shape[0], a_sep_cumsum))
    run_sum = np.sum(a_sep_cumsum[:,n:] - a_sep_cumsum[:,:-n], axis=0)

    return run_sum

run_sum_new(a, 3) = np.array([-9999.999966754345, -1.0861975537568031e-07, -6.766606211123526e-08, -5.270352127888686e-08, -4.5724870129252317e-08, -4.266522318456904e-08, -4.2191670372633516e-08, -4.393733278750304e-08])

a[:-2] + a[1:1] + a[2:] = 
np.array([-9999.999966754345, -1.0861975537568031e-07, -6.766606211123524e-08, -5.2703521278886865e-08, -4.572487012925232e-08, -4.266522318456905e-08, -4.2191670372633516e-08, -4.393733278750305e-08])

timeit.timeit('run_sum_new(a, 3)', number=1000, globals=globals()) = 0.12470354699999997


maybe you can try increase a precision by specifying data types of longdouble? np.cumsum(a, dtype=np.longdouble) ?

Also are you sure that data lost the precision? I mean how do you check that precision is not enough? Could you give an example? For example if you use print(b) and see only very large values it doesn't mean that individual items are rounded, it only says that print function truncates decimals.

Can you provide a [mre] that demonstrates this lack of precision?

I know about the print issue.

Here is an example:

I meant a short, well crafted example that show the issue of precision

@Oleg thanks for clarifying with an example. Indeed, there is a difference that is likely due to floating point arithmetics. Then the swv approach below might be what you need.

Could you explain what your actual application is? If some of your elements are O(1e8) and some are O(1e-8) and you are looking for 5 sig fig precision in the cumulative sum then you are probably asking for trouble with precision. If you explain your application then maybe someone can suggest "error-avoidance tactics".

@lastchance my final goal is to calculate integral of some functions that can change their values ​​over a large range and even have poles. The initial array is an array of values ​​of this function, calculated with some fixed argument increment. And its running sum is needed in order to scan the function and evaluate how far this function is from linear at each elementary interval, and to fit elementary integration intervals using this information. I.e. increase it if the deviation from linearity is less than the rounding error, and make it smaller otherwise.

Here's the idea I would suggest: have a fast path and an accurate path, and choose between them based on whether the fast path will produce the right answer.
A simple and fast way that you can implement a sum like this is to take the value that you used at the previous step, and subtract the element which will be removed from the window, and add the element which is entering the window.
However, the elements in the array vary by many orders of magnitude, this will result in a loss of precision, because subtracting a large element from the running sum will not completely remove it.
Therefore, I would suggest tracking how much error the result could have, relative to summing the numbers in the window, and in those cases, computing the sum. (I call this "restarting" the running sum, because it removes error accumulated from previous steps.)
I also used Numba so that I could write an efficient loop.
Example:
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


a = np.array([-9999.999966666666, -5.7847991744735696e-08, -2.983181169098924e-08, -2.093995193995538e-08, -1.6894298480290635e-08, -1.4869270858640853e-08, -1.3961300790320832e-08, -1.3834651535607362e-08, -1.4395718046705324e-08, -1.570696320519037e-08])

@nb.njit()
def run_sum_restart(a, n, rtol):
    eps = np.finfo(a.dtype).eps
    sum_ = a[:n].sum()
    out = np.zeros(len(a) - n + 1)
    out[0] = sum_
    addptr = n
    subptr = 0
    err = 0
    for i in range(1, len(out)):
        sum_ += a[addptr] - a[subptr]
        # Calculate max error for a[addptr] - a[subptr]
        err += (max(abs(a[addptr]), abs(a[subptr]))) * eps
        # Calculate max error for adding that to sum
        err += abs(sum_) * eps
        addptr += 1
        subptr += 1
        if err > rtol * abs(sum_):
            # Restart sum
            new_sum = a[subptr:addptr].sum()
            # print("Max relative error at ", err / sum_)
            # print("Restarted, found error of", (new_sum - sum_) / sum_)
            sum_ = new_sum
            err = 0
        out[i] = sum_
    return out


print(run_sum_restart(a, 3, rtol=1e-5))

Output:
[-9.99999997e+03 -1.08619755e-07 -6.76660621e-08 -5.27035213e-08
 -4.57248701e-08 -4.26652232e-08 -4.21916704e-08 -4.39373328e-08]

Benchmark timings for @mozway's benchmark:
Original
634 ms ± 5.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Restart sum version
582 ms ± 9.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

So this is both more accurate and faster.

Thank you! That's a good idea. Never used numba before

But I think I've found an even better way to do it. The idea is to split the array into large and small elements and independently calculate the cumsum. See update to my question.

If you want to do something similar to a for loop, you could use sliding_window_view:
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

b = swv(a, n).sum(axis=1)

This gives a very similar result to your function, which doesn't seem to lack precision:
# generate an input with a large variability
np.random.seed(0)
a = 1/np.random.random(size=100_000_000)*1e-8

a.min(), a.max()
# (1.0000000074212765e-08, 0.9650719974971247)

b1 = run_sum(a, n)
b2 = swv(a, n).sum(axis=1)

# are the two outputs almost equal?
np.allclose(b1, b2)
# True

# what is the greatest difference?
np.abs(b2-b1).max()
# 7.059628683189656e-15

but it is quite slower:
# run_sum(a, n)
895 ms ± 11.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# swv(a, n).sum(axis=1)
2.29 s ± 93.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


Thank you. Didn't know about this trick. Will try it. But the speed is also crusial

Thank you for the help. Guess I finally found more quick solution. The idea is to split the array into large and small elements and independently calculate the cumsum. See update to my question.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Large dataset
data = {'values': np.random.randint(1, 100000, size=1000000)}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
"""
        values
0        63699
1        43508
2        42814
3        41022
4        21850
...        ...
999995    8363
999996   48538
999997   81965
999998   16214
999999    4172
"""
n = 5  # Window size
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(df['values'].to_numpy(),n)
print('b :',b)
"""
b :  [[61846 93026 10783 15297  2129]
 [93026 10783 15297  2129 19732]
 [10783 15297  2129 19732 24161]
 ...
 [22289 12440 46910 58152 24534]
 [12440 46910 58152 24534 73633]
 [46910 58152 24534 73633 85820]]
"""
cumsum = np.cumsum(b,axis=1)

# Calculate the running sum using np.cumsum and select the last element of each window
Output = cumsum_last_elements = np.cumsum(b,axis=1)[:,-1]
#this the Output
print(cumsum_last_elements)
#CHECK. 1,000,000 - 5 + 1 = 999996 = Output shape should be (len(a) - n + 1) which is Correct
print(cumsum_last_elements.shape)

